# Replacing certain characters in email addresses with '*' in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to implement similar feature in my website and wanted to display email like below .

[image]

Below is the MYSQL code I have written and it is working OK for the scenarios I tested . But wanted to check with you guys if we have any better solution for this .

```
SELECT CONCAT(RPAD(CONCAT(RPAD(firstletter, firstpartlength - 2, '*'),
                   beforedomain), (
                            secondpartlength - Length(afterdot) +
                            firstpartlength ),
                     '*'), afterdot) hiddenemail
FROM   (SELECT SUBSTRING(email, 1, 1)                             firstletter,
               SUBSTRING(email, INSTR(email, '@') - 1, 3)         beforedomain,
               SUBSTR(SUBSTRING(email, INSTR(email, '@')),
               INSTR(SUBSTRING(email,
                     INSTR(email, '@')), '.'))
                      afterdot,
               LENGTH(SUBSTRING(email, 1, INSTR(email, '@') - 1))
               firstpartlength,
               LENGTH(SUBSTRING(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1))
               secondpartlength
        FROM   test_table) a
```

Thanks for your help

Regards
Kiran

Comment: I don't know your actual situation, but it might be better to implement a server-side scripting solution. For instance, if you are executing this SQL from a PHP script, PHP would be a better candidate for changing parts of the e-mail to asterisks.

Comment: Thank You David . Yes that is true . I am using PHP . Any quick script that is already available for this ?  Or I can write one myself ...

Comment: Consider emails like user@server.domain.tld - searching for last dot may be more appropriate. I'd leave such formatting to be done in code, rather than in DB, personally.

Comment: Thank You pjotr . That is true and I don't know why in the first shot I tried in MYSQL Query .. I will do that in PHP .. Please let me know if we have any thing available already ..

Comment: +1 for the effort you put into your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, I would recommend a PHP-based solution like this:

```
<?php
$email = 'youremail@ddre.ss';

$beforeAt=explode("@",$email);
$beforeAt=$beforeAt[0];
$asterisks=str_repeat("*",strlen($beforeAt)-2);
$beforeAt=$beforeAt{0}.$asterisks.substr($beforeAt,-1);
$domain=explode("@",$email);
$domain=explode(".",$domain[1]);
$extension=$domain[count($domain)-1];
$domain=implode(".",$domain);
$domain=substr($domain,0,-1*strlen($extension)-1);
$asterisks=str_repeat("*",strlen($domain)-1);
$email=$beforeAt."@".substr($domain,0,1).$asterisks.".".$extension;

echo $email;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution . Is there any way I can get like y*******l@d***.ss (  one character before @ and one character after @) . For now it is coming as y********@****.ss

Comment: Thank You David But still the Character after @ is not coming . Still it is coming as y********l@****.ss and not as y********l@d***.ss . I am trying to modify your initial solution .. From part2 getting the substring of last character and from part 5 getting the first character , But still checking it ..

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Didn't notice that part. I have updated the solution again. Test it at http://www.dstrout.net/pub/mask.php

Comment: It is worth noting that in the case of really short e-mail addresses (e.g. ab@u3.am) the whole thing will show, nothing will be masked. If you want, I can fix this, but for now short address will not be private.

Comment: Thank You for this wonderful solution and this works perfect ..Hope no company has email id like a@a.a  :)

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution without multiple selects:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(`email`,1,1),
    REPEAT('*',LOCATE('@',`email`)-3),
    SUBSTR(`email`,LOCATE('@',`email`)-1,3),
    REPEAT('*',LENGTH(`email`)-LOCATE('.',REVERSE(`email`))-LOCATE('@',`email`)-1),
    SUBSTR(`email`,LENGTH(`email`)-LOCATE('.',REVERSE(`email`)))
) 
FROM `accounts`;
```